# For axial flow compressor, at constant speed, does the required power changes as pressure ratio change?

Tags: compressors

For an axial compressor running at constant speed/rpm, does the power change as the pressure ratio increases and mass flow decreases (going up a constant speed line of a compressor map)? I am assuming the efficiency is constant throughout the compressor map.

I am trying to understand if, at a constant speed/rpm, the torque requirement changes as the pressure ratio increases (inlet pressure and temperature are constant).

Comment: Have you checked out the dimensionless groups used with pumps etc?

Comment: Check out Axial flow compressors in Engineering Thermodynamics Work & heat Transfer by Rogers & Mayhew. See page 448 onwards (third ed).